# CMSampleBuffer from OpenGL for video output with AVAssestWritter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, avassetwriter, core-motion

I need to get a CMSampleBuffer for the OpenGL frame. I'm using this:

```
int s = 1;
        UIScreen * screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
            s = (int)[screen scale];
        }
        const int w = viewController.view.frame.size.width/2;
        const int h = viewController.view.frame.size.height/2;
        const NSInteger my_data_length = 4*w*h*s*s;
        // allocate array and read pixels into it.
        GLubyte * buffer = malloc(my_data_length);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, w*s, h*s, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
        GLubyte * buffer2 = malloc(my_data_length);
        for(int y = 0; y < h*s; y++){
            memcpy(buffer2 + (h*s - 1 - y)*4*w*s, buffer + (4*y*w*s), 4*w*s);
        }
        free(buffer);
        CMBlockBufferRef * cm_block_buffer_ref;
        CMBlockBufferAccessDataBytes(cm_block_buffer_ref,0,my_data_length,buffer2,*buffer2);
        CMSampleBufferRef * cm_buffer;
        CMSampleBufferCreate (kCFAllocatorDefault,cm_block_buffer_ref,true,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,1,NULL,0,NULL,cm_buffer);
```

I get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS for CMSampleBufferCreate.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to use the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor class.

```
int s = 1;
        UIScreen * screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        if ([screen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
            s = (int)[screen scale];
        }
        const int w = viewController.view.frame.size.width/2;
        const int h = viewController.view.frame.size.height/2;
        const NSInteger my_data_length = 4*w*h*s*s;
        // allocate array and read pixels into it.
        GLubyte * buffer = malloc(my_data_length);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, w*s, h*s, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
        GLubyte * buffer2 = malloc(my_data_length);
        for(int y = 0; y < h*s; y++){
            memcpy(buffer2 + (h*s - 1 - y)*4*w*s, buffer + (4*y*w*s), 4*w*s);
        }
        free(buffer);
        CVPixelBufferRef pixel_buffer = NULL;
        CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes (NULL,w*2,h*2,kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,buffer2,4*w*s,NULL,0,NULL,&pixel_buffer);
        [av_adaptor appendPixelBuffer: pixel_buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: start_time],30)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the third parameter to `CMSampleBufferCreate()` true in your code?  According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMSampleBufferCreate):

> **Parameters**
>
> *allocator*
>
> The allocator to use to allocate memory for the CMSampleBuffer
>   object. Pass kCFAllocatorDefault to
>   use the current default allocator.
>
> *dataBuffer*
>
> This can be NULL, a CMBlockBuffer with no backing memory,
>   a CMBlockBuffer with backing memory
>   but no data yet, or a CMBlockBuffer
>   that already contains the media data.
>   Only in that last case (or if NULL and
>   numSamples is 0) should dataReady be
>   true.
>
> *dataReady*
>
> Indicates whether dataBuffer already contains the media
>   data.

Your `cm_block_buffer_ref` that is being passed in as a buffer contains no data (you should NULL it for safety, I don't believe the compiler does that by default), so you should use `false` here.

There may be other things wrong with this, but that's the first item that leaps out at me.

Comment: Thank you. How do I get cm_block_buffer_ref to contain the OpenGL data?

Comment: @Matthew - Looking at it, I think you'll need to create a CVPixelBuffer, then use `CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer()` instead of `CMSampleBufferCreate()`.  In fact, you're probably better off using an AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Oh yes, I added an answer of my own. I've managed to get it working (A bit slow but then glReadPixels is supposed to be). But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why the double malloc and why not swap in place via a temp buffer?

Something like this:

```
    GLubyte * raw = (GLubyte *) wyMalloc(size);
    LOGD("raw address %p", raw);
    glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, raw);
    const size_t end = h/2;
    const size_t W = 4*w;
    GLubyte row[4*w];
    for (int i=0; i <= end; i++) {
        void * top = raw + (h - i - 1)*W;
        void * bottom = raw + i*W;
        memcpy(row, top, W);
        memcpy(top, bottom, W);
        memcpy(bottom, row, W);
    }
```

Comment: I don't even malloc the original raw buffer anymore but instead recycle it.  I created a buffer pool class.  I do things slightly differently for my short loops. I save each image to storage then read them back in sequence at a later point.