# Layer OpenGL Content Over AVCaptureSession CVImageBufferRef from Camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have two successful concepts that I want to now merge. I am successful in layering a `CATextLayer` onto a `CVImageBufferRef` camera frame and then saving it via an `AVAssetWriter` using an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`. I do that like this:

```
- (void) processNewBuffer:(CVImageBufferRef)cameraFrame {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //    
    //    //update CALayer on main queue
    //    //UIKit is not thread safe
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        [self updateCALayer]; 
    });

    if(recorder.recording) {

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame,0); 

        // do stuff with buffer here
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame); 
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame); 
        width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame); 
        height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame); 

        /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

        [textLayer renderInContext:newContext];

        [recorder appendPixelBuffer:cameraFrame withPresentationTime:camera.lastSampleTime];

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame,0);

        /*We release some components*/
        CGContextRelease(newContext); 
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    }

    [pool drain]; 
}
```

This works like a charm. Now for my second trick. Thanks to the answer to this question:

[CMSampleBuffer from OpenGL for video output with AVAssestWritter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824173/cmsamplebuffer-from-opengl-for-video-output-with-avassestwritter)

I can modify the OpenGL Teapot example from the WWDC 2010 sample code and save the rendered content to a movie file on the iPhone.

NOW, what I want is the ability to layer the teapot in one corner of the camera frame, and save the bundle to a movie. The problem that I am having is basic C stuff. How do I copy from one buffer to the next, when one buffer is 1280x720 (the camera frame) and the teapot is in a buffer that is 320x320. The other consideration is speed. In order to process 30fps, I can't be moving in and out of either CGImageRef or UIImage classes. This has to happen as fast as possible. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the SpriteKit Framework ( from iOS7 ) that works on OpenGL and should keep high frame rates, working on images/texture.

Start looking on Apple introduction: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH1-SW1

Hope it helps